# Why does Firefox is block my fetch request to localhost from a content-script?

Tags: javascript, http, firefox, cors, firefox-addon-webextensions

I have a simple HTTP-server running on http://localhost:8081 it has a GET route "/tts" and always responds with cors headers:

```
self.send_header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
self.send_header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "*")
self.send_header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "*")
```

A WebExtension I'm currently writing is simply executing a content-script on a specific domain, let's call it `https://somedomain.com/*` .

The content script is trying to run:

```
fetch("http://localhost:8081/tts?text=test").catch(console.error)
```

But when it tires to send this simple GET request to my http-server, it doesn't show up in the network tab of the dev tools and it also never reaches my server. All I get is an error on the console: `TypeError: NetworkError when attempting to fetch resource.`

This is my manifest btw:

```
{
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "content_scripts": [{
        "matches": ["https://somedomain.com/*"],
        "js": ["content-script.js"]
    }],
    "permissions": [
        "https://somedomain.com/*",
        "http://localhost:8081/*",
        "http://localhost:8081/tts*",
        "http://localhost:8081/tts/*",
        "http://localhost:8081/tts?*",
        "http://localhost:8081/tts?text=*",
        "tabs"
    ],
    ...
```

The HTTP-server is working fine btw. When I execute the fetch call in the console manually on somedomain.com it works just fine:

```
fetch("http://localhost:8081/tts?text=test").catch(console.error)
```

How could I fix this?

**Edit:**
I just tested it in Chrome and the same extension works just fine there. So it must be a Firefox-specific issue I guess.

**Edit 2:**
Sending the request from a background script works fine as well.
It's only when I send the request from the content-script in Firefox that it doesn't work.

Comment: I haven't tried it in Chrome. I'm writing a WebExtension for Firefox. How could I remove the http restriction?